# Axis Aligned Bounding Box Collision Detection Issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have attempted to produce an algorithm that uses world coordinates and a bounding box structure to
detect collision between two bounding boxes. I really don't know what I'm doing, but I thought the code below would work. My issue is that it only detects collision if the bounding boxes are on the exact same x,y,z position.

```
BOOL AABB::isCollidedWith(AABB* bb)
{
if(bb == NULL) return FALSE;

float radX1,radX2;
float radY1,radY2;
float radZ1,radZ2;

float arr[12];

      //please note that all the mins are set to 0
      //and all the maxes are set to 1

radX1 = (bb->maxX - bb->minX) / 2;
radX2 = (this->maxX - this->minX) / 2;
radY1 = (bb->maxY - bb->minY) / 2;
radY2 = (this->maxY - this->minY) / 2;
radZ1 = (bb->maxZ - bb->minZ) / 2;
radZ2 = (this->maxZ - this->minZ) / 2;

//bb coords

arr[1] = bb->bbX - radX1;
arr[2] = bb->bbX + radX1;
arr[3] = bb->bbY - radY1;
arr[4] = bb->bbY + radY1;
arr[5] = bb->bbZ - radZ1;
arr[6] = bb->bbZ + radZ1;

//this coords
arr[7]  = this->bbX - radX2;
arr[8]  = this->bbX + radX2;
arr[9]  = this->bbY - radY2;
arr[10] = this->bbY + radY2;
arr[11] = this->bbZ - radZ2;
arr[12] = this->bbZ + radZ2;

if(arr[2] >= arr[7] && arr[1] <= arr[8])
{
    if(arr[4] >= arr[9] && arr[3] <= arr[10])
    {
        if(arr[6] >= arr[11] && arr[5] <= arr[12])
        {
            this->collided = TRUE;
            OutputDebugStringA("Collided!\n");
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Structures I am comparing:

```
 AABB* aabb1 = new AABB(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
 AABB* aabb2 = new AABB(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
 aabb2->isCollidedWith(aabb1);
```

Constructor snippet :
Also note that the last three parameters dictate the x,y,z cords of the bounding box

```
AABB::AABB(float minx,float maxx,float miny,float maxy,float minz,float maxz,float x,float y,float z)
{
this->minX = minx;
this->maxX = maxx;
this->minY = miny;
this->maxY = maxy;
this->minZ = minz;
this->maxZ = maxz;
```

Any help,criticism, or advice would help.

Comment: Can you give an example of a collision that does work, and one that doesn't work?

Comment: AABB* aabb1 = new AABB(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f) AABB* aabb2 = new AABB(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f) works.

Comment: AABB* aabb1 = new AABB(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f) AABB* aabb2 = new AABB(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f) doesn't work.

Comment: Basically when aabb2's x y or z are greater than 0.

Comment: Avoid the use of `new` java-like sintax

Comment: And to pass by reference, use a reference, not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating the boxes with minX=0.0 and maxX=0.0, the `bbX` coordinate must be the same for the boxes to collide (because radX = 0). The same goes for minZ=maxZ=1.0.

Note the order of parameters in your constructor: it's `minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ` and **not** `minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ` (I guess you supposed the second order and wanted to define a box of 1.0 x 1.0 x 1.0 dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

Simple Error! I ignored the way the parameters were listed, causing the issue.
Also, I had subtract 0.5 from each member of the  array "arr" to find the center of AABB.